# request SQL 2 Left outer join

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

i tried to create a request with double LETF OUTER JOIN with sequelize without success 
i have 2 table : Users

[image: user]

And : friends

[image: friends]

my userid and idfriend are related to my table user

if i have on my table user 
Id = X , userId = 23 , idFriend = 34 ,...

i have a query who provide me all row who have for example 23 (userID or Idfriend)
how can i get the all the data of userId (username, email ...) and all the data idFriend(username, email ...) in the same request

thx

Comment: I don't understand the database design.. why do you need 3 ids column in the friend table (id, idfriend and userId)

Comment: @marius what design would you suggest me ?

Comment: for me id and idFriend from the Friend table seems to be the same thing, the id from the Friend table. I don't understand why do you need both fields.

Comment: Id is the Id of the relationship issuer is related to the table user and Idfriend is related too to the user table

Comment: sorry. i don't understand.. 
so you have user table (row1: Id: 1, name='x', ...., row2: Id = 2, name = 'y'..  and table friends with row1: Id = 1, UserId = 2 that link to the row2 from users). 
You have the userId field to link friends table with users.

Comment: I have my table who regroup all my user (username mail age ...) and my table friends. This table regroup the friendship relation between users. So if in my table friends I have Id : x iduser : 1 , idfriend : 56 i know tha user 1 is friend with user 56

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169465/discussion-between-marius-and-tetar).

Answer (score 0):

you should left join the user two time eg:

```
  select a.userId, a.Idfriend, b.username as  username, c.username as friendname 
  from  friends a
  left join user b on b.id = a.userId 
  left join user c on c.id = a.idfriend
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it which sequelize ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you are trying to get data for userId and friendId with one query? I think this must work for you, but you need to test it

First way:

```
SELECT user.*, friend.* FROM users
LEFT JOIN users as user ON user.id=23
LEFT JOIN users as friend ON friend.id=34
LIMIT 1
```

Second way using UNION:

```
(SELECT user.*, friend.* FROM users as user
LEFT JOIN users as friend ON friend.id=23
WHERE user.id=34 OR user.id IS NULL)
UNION
(SELECT user.*, friend.* FROM users as user
RIGHT JOIN users as friend ON friend.id=34
WHERE user.id=23 OR user.id IS NULL)
```

Another way (this way have risk to return you empty if WHERE clause is null):

```
SELECT user.*, friend.* FROM users as user
JOIN users as friend ON friend.id=34
WHERE user.id=23
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Do you know how can I do it with sequelize